# How to send an email only to users who appear in query results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a query to return tickets that haven't been updated in the required time and send via email. I have everything working except I want to email only the users whose names appear in the query results.

I have tried setting the @ user name = to user id and adding to the email as below. Not sure if this is even close.

```
Declare @username VARCHAR(MAX)
--("query")--
Set @username =[userid]--(in query results)--

exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@participants ='@username+@mydomain.com'
```

Expect to send emails to users whose user name appears in query results.

Comment: Use CURSOR https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/fetch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: If you're doing this as part of a sproc, I get it. If you're not, say you're doing this as part of a scheduled job. Consider using Powershell. https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/powershell.aspx?cat=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/889561/1507566

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Coalesce to create a list separated with semicolons which is what dbmail wants.

```
Declare @username varchar(max)

SELECT 
    @username = COALESCE(@username + '; ','') + userid + '@mydomain'
FROM 
    Yourtable   
WHERE 
    Yourquery

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @recipients = @username
    @subject = 'BARK BARK'
    @Body = 'BARK BARK BARK'
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i was looking for. I am using joins from multiple tables to make this query work I have tried putting the query results in to a temp table and setting the above from to read from that table. while it works and sends to the users it no longer contains the rest of the information from the query. Any suggestions?

Comment: What other info are you trying to include? You might try experimenting with a second variable that uses the the same setup as the (at)username but would be (at)users if you want it to be from people in your query. If you want the body of the message to be different for each one it gets more complicated. That would require either the cursor methods or getting creative with the @query parameter of dbmail. [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `STUFF` with `FOR XML PATH` to create a `;` delimited list for the `@recipients` parameter:

```
DECLARE @EmailList varchar(max)
SELECT @EmailList = STUFF((
                        SELECT ';' + Username + '@gmail.com'
                        FROM yourTable
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 1, '')
```

Then:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @recipients = @EmailList,
     @subject = 'foo',
     @body = 'bar',
     etc
```

Comment: `STUFF` can not create a delimited list.  In your query this is `FOR XML PATH` business.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CURSOR` to fetch your email address list and send the email to that list:

```
DECLARE @username AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @participants AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR
FOR
SELECT userid
FROM YourTable

OPEN cursor_name;

FETCH NEXT
FROM cursor_name
INTO @username;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    @participants += @username + '@mydomain.com;'

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name
    INTO @username;
END

CLOSE cursor_name;
DEALLOCATE cursor_name;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = @participants 
etc
```

Comment: I get a " incorrect syntax near @participants" error

Comment: Try to initialize both variables as empty; username = '' and participants = ''